# Running into problems with class inheritance an tkinter listBox insert

Tags: python, tkinter, audio-player

I am currently trying to make a simple Jukebox/Music Player in Python and ran into some concerns with class inheritance and tkinter's listBox method.

I have to two classes JukeboxGUI and JukeboxContent (the content one is incomplete). The JukeboxContent class inherits the JukeboxGUI:

```
import os
import pygame
#from PIL import Image
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from tkinter import *
import eyed3


class JukeboxGUI: 
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.photo = PhotoImage(file = "//Users//nukhbahmajid//Desktop//Jukebox//background2.gif")
        self.canvas = Canvas(width = 1000, height = 1000, bg = "black")
        self.label = Label(self.canvas, text = "Jukebox")
        self.listBox = Listbox(self.canvas)
        self.playPauseButton = Button(self.canvas, text = "Play / Pause")
        self.nextButton = Button(self.canvas, text = "Next Song")
        self.previousButton = Button(self.canvas, text = "Previous Song")
        self.stopButton = Button(self.canvas, text = "Stop")
        self.labelVar = StringVar()
        self.songLabel = Label(self.canvas, textvariable = self.labelVar, width = 20)

    def constructButtons(self):
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0, image = self.photo, anchor = NW)
        self.label = self.canvas.create_window(325, 40, anchor = NW, window = self.label)
        self.listBox = self.canvas.create_window(270, 80, anchor = NW, window = self.listBox)
        self.playPauseButton = self.canvas.create_window(110, 120, anchor = NW, window = self.playPauseButton)
        self.nextButton = self.canvas.create_window(500, 120, anchor = NW, window = self.nextButton)
        self.previousButton = self.canvas.create_window(500, 180, anchor = NW, window = self.previousButton)
        self.stopButton = self.canvas.create_window(130, 183, anchor = NW, window = self.stopButton)
        self.songLabel = self.canvas.create_window(268, 268, anchor = NW, window = self.songLabel)


class JukeboxContent(JukeboxGUI):
    def __init__(self, window):
        #JukeboxGUI.__init__(self, window)
        super(JukeboxContent, self).__init__(window)
        listOfSongs = []
        songTitles = []
        num_songs = len(songTitles)
        self.index = 1
        self.listOfSongs = listOfSongs
        self.songTitles = songTitles
        self.directoryAsk = askdirectory()
        self.num_songs = num_songs
        self.Error_NoMP3s = "No \".mp3\" files found."

    def directoryChooser(self):
        self.directoryAsk
        os.chdir(self.directoryAsk)

        for files in os.listdir(self.directoryAsk):
            if files.endswith(".mp3"):
                realdir = os.path.realpath(files)
                audioTag = eyed3.load(realdir)
                self.songTitles.append(audioTag.tag.title)
                self.listOfSongs.append(files)
                print(files) ## comment out or remove later
                print("These are the Song titles:", self.songTitles) #check if the list gets appended

        for items in self.songTitles:
            self.listBox.insert(END, items) ## the list doesn't get inserted into the listbox


        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load(self.listOfSongs[0])
        self.labelVar.set(self.songTitles[0])
        print("The label variable:", self.labelVar) ## the variable isn't set either
        print("The label is accessible:", self.songLabel) ## songLabel doesn't get updated
        pygame.mixer.music.play() # the song doesn't play 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("700x500+450+200")
    window.title("Jukebox")
    constructGUI = JukeboxGUI(window)
    constructGUI.constructButtons()
    initiateJukebox = JukeboxContent(window)
    initiateJukebox.directoryChooser()
    window.mainloop()
```

When I try to access the attributes of the parent class, like inserting the songs into the list box, there isn't an error here specifically, but the list isn't into the box either

Secondly, when I update the label variable and songLabel, and try to print out later to see if it was implemented, the following gets printed to the terminal:

```
The label variable: PY_VAR1
The label is accessible: .!canvas2.!label2
```

The song doesn't play either. What could be the problem? Please help me out! Here's a picture of the interface if it helps:
[JukeboxInterface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW5aK.jpg)

Comment: Change to `print("The label variable:", self.labelVar.get())`. This `self.songLabel = self.canvas` overwrites the previos `self.songLabel = ...`.

Comment: @stovfl Thank you! I was now able to get the label variable after appending ".get()". I don't quite understand why the "songLabel" won't print to the interface. Could you please tell me why the list of songs is not being inserted in the listbox? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Please **don't** repaeat your Question. What you think about `self.songLabel`?